# smarty cannot locate directories on /home

Tags: php, smarty

I've got `/usr/local/lib/php/Smarty/Smarty.class.php` and I've put my Smarty templates, cache and other directories in `/home/groucho/Code/PHP/smarty/`.

This is my `index.php` file in `/var/www/sapienter` (which is my app folder):

```
<?php
// put full path to Smarty.class.php
require('/usr/local/lib/php/Smarty/Smarty.class.php');
$smarty = new Smarty();

$smarty->setTemplateDir('/home/groucho/Code/PHP/smarty/templates');
$smarty->setCompileDir('/home/groucho/Code/PHP/smarty/templates_c');
$smarty->setCacheDir('/home/groucho/Code/PHP/smarty/cache');
$smarty->setConfigDir('/home/groucho/Code/PHP/smarty/configs');

$smarty->testInstall();


$smarty->assign('name', 'Ned');
$smarty->display('index.tpl');

?>
```

But this doesn't work, since it gives me this output:

```
Smarty Installation test...
Testing template directory...
FAILED: /home/groucho/Code/PHP/smarty/templates/ does not exist.
Testing compile directory...
FAILED: /home/groucho/Code/PHP/smarty/templates_c/ does not exist.
Testing plugins directory...
/usr/local/lib/php/Smarty/plugins is OK.
Testing cache directory...
FAILED: /home/groucho/Code/PHP/smarty/cache/ does not exist.
Testing configs directory...
FAILED: /home/groucho/Code/PHP/smarty/configs/ does not exist.
Testing sysplugin files...
... OK
Testing plugin files...
... OK
Tests complete.


Fatal error: Uncaught --> Smarty: Unable to load template file 'index.tpl' <-- thrown in /usr/local/lib/php/Smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php on line 127
```

`/home/groucho/Code/PHP/smarty` folder permissions are set by `chmod -R 775`, and I'm the owner.

If I put the `templates` folder and the other ones directly in `/var/www/sapienter` and I write

```
$smarty->setTemplateDir('/var/www/sapienter/templates');
```

it works.

Why is that? Why does `/var` path works and `/home` doesn't?

Comment: add `phpinfo()` to your script and check if the `open_basedir` directive  is set. Another option would be restrictive permissions in the directory path (it's not enough to set chmod for the smarty folder, if for example /home/groucho is too restricitve the webserver will not be able to reach directories further down)

Comment: @GeraldSchneider :`open_basedir` has "no value". Should I set it? **EDIT:** Ok I don't think I have to change it. My /home folder permissions are set on drwxr-xr-x root root. Should I change them?